# How to submit new build for review?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have multiple versions of the same app in my iTunes Connect account. I want to submit the most recent version while it is still waiting for review but I can't seem to figure out how to submit my new version of the build. Can anyone help me out please? Thanks for the help!![image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out the issue. The problem was I did not remove the old build before trying to submit the new one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The image you are showing is displaying the *Prerelease*-Section which will release your app for Beta Testers using TestFlight. You will want to go to **Versions** and then **scroll down** until you see the following screen:

[image: iTunesConnect - Upload Build section]

There, you'll want to **upload** the build from inside **Xcode** and then **submit** it for review.

Hope that helps you :)

Comment: I tried this but there is only one build in that section. Just 1.0.

Comment: Well then upload the newer one? I believe you don't even have to delete the older one.

Comment: I will update the question with what I am seeing now.

Comment: You have to upload the new build (with another version name) inside Xcode.

Comment: It is not there I am not sure if I am doing something wrong? I'll update the picture one more time to show the full section. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MbusiHlatshwayo changed my comment, mixed something up there :D